# Why does there exist a deck transformation mapping here?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

See Kevin Dong's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1414445/149792).

> Let $\widetilde{\gamma}$ be a path in $X_N$ based at $x_0^N \in X_N$ with $p(\widetilde{\gamma}) = \gamma$ a nontrivial path in $X$. Since the cover is normal, there exists a deck transformation mapping $x_0^N$ to any other preimage under $p$ of $x_0 \in X$. (Why?)

I do not follow why the existence of such a deck transformation mapping follows from the normality of the cover... can someone explain?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a normal cover? Are you asking why the cover is normal, why a cover corresponding to a normal subgroup is a normal cover, something else?

Comment: It's not clear to me why the existence of a deck transformation mapping follows from the normality of the cover.

Comment: ["Now suppose $p : C → X$ is a covering map and $C$ (and therefore also $X$) is connected and locally path connected. The action of $Aut(p)$ on each fiber is free. If this action is transitive on some fiber, then it is transitive on all fibers, and we call the cover regular (or normal or Galois)."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) It's literally the definition of a normal cover, a cover is normal iff for every pair of points in a fiber, there's a deck transformation mapping the first point to the second.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space):

> Now suppose $p:C \to X$ is a covering map and $C$ (and therefore also $X$) is connected and locally path connected. The action of $Aut(p)$ on each fiber is free. If this action is transitive on some fiber, then it is [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Transitive) on all fibers, and we call the cover regular (or normal or Galois).

By the very definition of what a normal cover is, the fact that the cover $p : X_N \to X$ is normal implies that for any $x_0^N \in p^{-1}(x_0)$ and any other point $y \in p^{-1}(x_0)$, there is a deck transformation $\sigma \in Aut(p)$ such that $\sigma(x_0^N) = y$. This is what an action being *transitive* means. Here, the cover is normal because it corresponds to a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$, a standard fact in algebraic topology (you can find the proof in any textbook).